# python subprocess.Popen.communicate() closes p.stdout and p.stderr files, but where?

Tags: python, subprocess

```
p = subprocess.Popen("sleep 5 ; ls -l", shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
```

I was looking at `/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py`

I see quite explicitly that both `stdout` and `stderr` are closed in `p.communicate()` for the case when either `stdout` or `sdterr` are `None` in addition to `stdin`.

However I could not figure out where in the code does the call to `_communicate()` close the `p.stdout` and `p.stderr` for the Popen object when only `stdin` is `None` as in my example above?

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `_communicate_with_poll`, the close is done in `close_unregister_and_remove` and in `_communicate_with_select` there are two lines of code `self.stdout.close()` and `seld.stderr.close()` that do the job. There is a third implementation of `_communicate` but it's only used on MS Windows. That implementation doesn't seem to close `stdout` and `stderr`!

Comment: Thanks. Its lines 1219 and 1226 in _communicate() ( line 1175) in /usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py. I was looking at the windows _communicate initially and there, as you confirmed the PIPES are not closed.

Comment: In 3.2/3.3, the [`_readerthread`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bd8afb90ebf2/Lib/subprocess.py#l1154) used on Windows does close the file.